# Duvida sobre formulário modal em aplicação MDI

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe3

Bom, vou tentar resumir. Possuo uma aplicação MDI a qual gostaria que os formulários "MODAL" ficassem sobrepostos somente aos formulários "fsMDIChild" e não sobre toda a aplicação. Realizei uma pesquisa e não obtive uma solução através do showmodal, parece que não tem como fazer. Minha dúvida: existe alguma maneira de criar uma "tipo" de formulário que fique a frente dos formulários dentro da aplicação MDI e que ao mesmo tempo me permita minimizar a aplicação?

Exemplo grotesco: Vária telas de cadastro abertas e ao clicar no botão excluir de uma delas 
apareça a mensagem "Deseja realmente excluir?". Essa mensagem de confirmação eu gostaria que ficasse a frente das telas de cadastro, ficasse dentro da área da aplicação, conforme ficam os "fsMDIChild" e ao mesmo tempo me permitisse minimizar o formulário principal.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou utilizar o `BringToFront`?

Com o trecho de código abaixo retirado do *help* do Delphi você pode adaptar para usa realidade, tente usar o `BringToFront` para manter sua tela de pergunta acima das outras telas filhas.

```
procedure TForm1.ShowPaletteButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Form2.Visible = False then Form2.Visible := True;
  Form2.BringToFront;
end;
```